# Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $E \subseteq Y$ Prove that $X \backslash \bar f^{-1}(E) \subseteq \bar f^{-1}(Y \backslash E)$

Tags: functions

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $E \subseteq Y$ Prove that $X \backslash \bar f^{-1}(E) \subseteq \bar f^{-1}(Y \backslash E)$

The $\bar f^{-1}$ is a power set function. So it's all about proving that a powerset  function is a subset to another powerset function?

Here's what I got so far. If I split the question up into pieces, I know that E is a subset of Y. I also know that for a function $f: X\rightarrow Y$  the element $x \in X$ is paired with $y \in Y$ and that's written as $f(x) = y$. The set X is the domain and the set Y is the codomain of $f$. If $f(x) = y$, then y is the image of x and x is the preimage of y.

If I use the complement definition for $X \backslash \bar f^{-1}(E) \subseteq \bar f^{-1}(Y \backslash E)$, then

$X \backslash \bar f^{-1}(E) = [x: x \in X, x \notin f^{-1}(E)]$ which means that x belongs in X.

$\bar f^{-1}(Y \backslash E)$ = $[x: x \in y, x \notin E]$ so x belongs to y... and I'll have $\bar f^{-1}(Y)$ left over

Definition 5.3.8 states that we let $f : X \rightarrow Y$. For each set $B \in \mathcal P \left({Y}\right),$ define the function  $\bar f^{-1}: \mathcal P \left({Y}\right) \rightarrow \mathcal P \left({X}\right) $ by $\bar f^{-1}(B) : [ x \in X :f(x) \in B]$

In my problem, for each set $E \in \mathcal P \left({Y}\right),$ define the function  $\bar f^{-1}: \mathcal P \left({Y}\right) \rightarrow \mathcal P \left({X}\right) $ by $\bar f^{-1}(E) : [ x \in X :f(x) \in E]$

If I negate the statement, it's

$\bar f^{-1}: \mathcal P \left({Y}\right) \rightarrow \mathcal P \left({X}\right) $ by $\bar f^{-1}(E) : [ x \notin X :f(x) \notin E]$

So x doesn't belong in X and the $f(x)$ doesn't belong in E. But, I don't know what to do next. Assuming that I could use the complement definitions from earlier, I have $X \subseteq \bar f^{-1} (Y)$ remaining.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things. Just do an element chase.  Let $x \in X \setminus f^{-1}(E)$.  Then $f(x) \notin E$, so that $f(x) \in Y \setminus E$.  Thus $x \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus E)$.

QED.

Comment: How am I overcomplicating things? Just curious... I saw some $\backslash$ and I figured out that's complement definition, so I'll use that. Alright I see that that the $f(x) \notin E$ part.. so... umm wait does that apply to $x \backslash f^{-1} (E)$?

Comment: Yeah, since $X \setminus f^{-1}(E)$ is by definition the set of all  elements of $X$ that do not belong to $f^{-1}(E)$.  So if $x \notin f^{-1}(E)$, then $f(x) \notin E$.

Comment: alright...so yes there are elements in x, but not in $f^{-1}(E)$ since $f(x) \notin E$ that would mean that for $ Y \backslash E$ part .. there are elements in Y but again not in E. Yet from $E \subseteq Y$ that would mean that there are E elements in Y. E...is just no element...sorry that's empty set.. E just doesn't belong... so E doesn't belong in Y for $E \subseteq Y$?